# android set bounds for one layer of layer drawable

Tags: android, android-widget, drawable, bounds

I'm trying to use a `LayerDrawable` for a custom UI widget and have one layer be drawn with different bounds than the other layers, but it doesn't seem to be working. Essentially, my code does this:

```
int left, top, right, bottom;
/*... do some math ... */
Drawable d = mDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.some_specific_layer);
d.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Meanwhile, the xml looks like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#ff999999" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@id/some_specific_layer"
    android:drawable="@drawable/some_drawable"/>
```

So ideally I would see some_drawable over a gray rectangle, with the amount of gray showing from behind depending on the result of the bounds computation. But I never see any of the gray layer, and it appears to be because it's bounds also are being set somehow.

**EDIT**

Here's a visual of desired versus expected result:
[image]

The top image is what I want to achieve; the gray corresponds to the first layer and the gradient corresponds to the second layer with the predefined `id`. The actual result never shows the gray.

Does anyone know if it's possible to set the bounds of one layer of a `LayerDrawable` without affecting other layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some responses from the Android Developers Google Group. Essentially, there's no reliable way to do this with `LayerDrawable` since it manages the state for all it's child `Drawables`. I've since adopted an approach that uses two separate drawables instead, with satisfactory results. Here's the discussion thread for reference:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-developers/fUxtJstdkBM/discussion

Comment: Please add code sample or describe solution for the problem, since this url and discussion with solution are not accessible

Comment: Unfortunately I don't recall the details of the discussion, nor the solution I ended up with. I probably just used a background image or drew the drawables myself on a Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do a similar thing with this code, using a LayerDrawable :

```
// create first shape
ShapeDrawable shape1 = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
shape1.getPaint().setColor(0xFFFFFF00);
shape1.setIntrinsicWidth(50);
shape1.setIntrinsicHeight(50);
shape1.invalidateSelf();

// create second shape
ShapeDrawable shape2 = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
shape2.getPaint().setColor(0xFFFFB400);
shape2.setIntrinsicWidth(20);
shape2.setIntrinsicHeight(50);
shape2.invalidateSelf();

// create layerDrawable (layer-list in xml)
// it containt our 2 shapes and the order in wich they will be drawn (shape2 is on top).
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{shape1, shape2});

// ajust position shape1 and shape2
layerDrawable.setLayerInset(0, 0,0,0,0);
layerDrawable.setLayerInset(1, 15,0,15,0);
```

The result is (on a black background):

[image]